# Setting textbox value from datalist item click without postback?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-4.0

I have a `datalist` within a `panel` that looks like the following. Each datalist item (with `LinkButton` and `CommandArgument`) displays the roomNum.

Without doing `PostBack`, I'm trying to populate `textbox TextBoxRoomNum` with *RoomNum* from `Label1` in the datalist item. I assume it will be done with `javascript`.

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelRoomDetail" runat="server" style="position:absolute; width:600px; height: 600px; display:none">
    <telerik:RadTabStrip RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="RadTabStrip1" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1" SelectedIndex="0" >
        <Tabs>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="Assign" Width="200px"></telerik:RadTab>
        </Tabs>
    </telerik:RadTabStrip>
    <telerik:RadMultiPage runat="server" ID="RadMultiPage1"  SelectedIndex="0">
        <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageView2">
            <div style="width: 600px; height: 200px; ">
                <div style="width: 600px;">
                    <asp:DataList ID="DataListFloorThumb" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="width:72px;height:72px">
                            <asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" runat="server">

                                <div style='background-image:url(<%# Eval("image_path","Styles/Images/{0}") %>)'>
                                    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
                                        <div style="text-align: left; float:left;">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RoomNum")%>' CommandName="cmd_RoomNum" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RoomNum")%>' Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="11pt"></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxRoomNum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
        </telerik:RadPageView>
    </telerik:RadMultiPage>
</asp:Panel>
```

This can be easily done if the page does postback, but without postback I assume it requires some javascript, and that's where I'm stuck. I prefer no jquery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As with any server-side control, you can add an `OnClientClick` attribute that will execute the javascript you enter in the attribute value:

> disclaimer: not tested. Not sure of Eval syntax, that always bite me. Not doing proper null checking. Script pollutes global scope.

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
     OnClientClick='return ShowRoom(<%# Eval("RoomNum")%>);' />
```

...somewhere else:

```
<script>
      function ShowRoom(room){
          var txtBox = document.querySelector("#TextBoxRoomNum");
          txtBox.value = room;
          return false;
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention in the code the panel uses a `ModalPopupExtender`. Would that affect the solution? It seem that when I click on the datalist, the popup disappears, and I assume it's because it's doing some partial postback?

Comment: @rbhatup, I really can't say how that would behave. The modal should still be able to access the javascript. Maybe don't return false? I doubt it is doing a partial postback.